# Firebase imported but cannot be used

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase

Im simply just trying to pair up Facebook login with `Firebase`. 
I'm creating a singleton where it has reference to my firebase project but it won't let me initialize firebase. Ive imported every pod I can and it still won't work.

I'm getting below error.

[image]

Its driving me crazy.. is this deprecated or something?

Heres my pod file

[image]

Comment: That is that exact same question.. thank you for that! Weird, I googled for "firebase init error" and "fire base import not working" and I couldn't find that :P

Comment: Usually it's good practice to google the error printed after the little red alert symbol. That usually turns something up.

Comment: Will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of `Firebase`, you need to use `FIRDatabase.database().reference()` instead of `Firebase(url: url)`, if you doesn't know about this, check the latest Firebase [documentation for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

If you are upgrading your existing app that uses `Firebase.com` to the new `Firebase console` and `APIs` the check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) of `Firebase`for that.

Also you can check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0MuaFzoxng) on `iOS Swift Tutorial: Get started with Firebase and an App like Twitter`